# What are the required props used for when using withScriptjs HOC

Tags: react-google-maps

Just started using `react-google-maps` and would like to know what the required properties loadingElement, containerElement, and mapElement are used for when using the `withScriptsjs` HOC.  Are they strictly used for styling as the examples show?  Again I'm not exactly sure what these properties are used for.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about the `containerElement` and `mapElement` props that are associated with the [`withGoogleMap` HOC](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#withgooglemap).

If you do not include either the `containerElement` or `mapElement` props (test it out in [this CodeSanbox demo app](https://codesandbox.io/s/2xyw6n4o9y)), you get the following error:

> Required props containerElement or mapElement is missing. You need to
>   provide both of them.
>   The `google.maps.Map` instance will be
>   initialized on mapElement and it's wrapped by containerElement. You
>   need to provide both of them since Google Map requires the DOM to have
>   height when initialized.

The way I see it, the `mapElement` prop is used to specify the HTML element that the map will attach too.

In a [simple Vanilla JavaScript example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple#try-it-yourself)(taken from the Google Maps Documentation), this is represented by the following code:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

The first argument to the `google.maps.Map` constructor is the DOM element in which you want to create the new map. In the JS example, this is the `div` element with an `id` of "map" inside the body tag (`<div id="map"></div>`).

As for the `containerElement` prop: the same JS example does not explicitly specify a container element because I believe the `body` and `html` elements are assumed to be the containers. That is why the CSS specifies a height for them:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This ties in with the following part of the error I shared above:

> ... Google Map requires the DOM to have height when initialized.

If you remove the `height: 100%` CSS rule from the JS example (try removing it from the CSS in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hukoquq/edit?css,output)), the map doesn't show up anymore. This might be equivalent to removing the `containerElement` prop.

---

Regarding the `loadingElement` prop, I'm not sure what that is for yet... :)